# How to get the data of product Name at once and display it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

On my last post, I asked how to get the data under foods, which is the product Name. Now I'm having problem getting every product Name data and show it all at once.

firebase and recycler view:
[image]

*MainAcvity*

```
databaseReference.child("Requests").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        // clear old items / users from list to add new data/ users
        myItemsList.clear();

        // getting all children from users root
        for (DataSnapshot Requests : snapshot.getChildren()) {

            // to prevent app crash check if the user has all the details in Firebase Database
            if (Requests.hasChild("askfor") && Requests.hasChild("tablet") && Requests.hasChild("total")) {

                // getting users details from Firebase Database and store into the List one by one
                final String getaskfor = Requests.child("askfor").getValue(String.class);
                final String gettablet = Requests.child("tablet").getValue(String.class);
                final String gettotal = Requests.child("total").getValue(String.class);
                // final String getproductName = Requests.child("productName").getValue(String.class);


                String getproductName = "null";
                if (Requests.hasChild("foods")) {
                    for (DataSnapshot foodSnapshot : Requests.child("foods").getChildren()) {
                        getproductName = foodSnapshot.child("productName").getValue(String.class);
                    }
                }
                // creating user item with user details
                MyItems myItems = new MyItems(getaskfor, gettablet, gettotal, getproductName);

                // adding this user item to List
                myItemsList.add(myItems);
```

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: No errors, since it can get the data of product Name. It can get the data once but not every data in multiple product Name. What I want to get is every data of product Name every time there is a data under it. Like shown in the picture it only show once and didn't get the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

To get all product names as a single string, you can do:

```
String getproductName = "null";
if (Requests.hasChild("foods")) {
    for (DataSnapshot foodSnapshot : Requests.child("foods").getChildren()) {
        getproductName = getproductName + foodSnapshot.child("productName").getValue(String.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all set the "Request" variable with a lowercase (requests)

```
      myItemsList.clear();

        // getting all children from users root
        for (DataSnapshot requests : snapshot.getChildren()) {

            // to prevent app crash check if the user has all the details in Firebase Database
            if (Requests.hasChild("askfor") && Requests.hasChild("tablet") && Requests.hasChild("total")) {

                // getting users details from Firebase Database and store into the List one by one
                final String getaskfor = Requests.child("askfor").getValue(String.class);
                final String gettablet = Requests.child("tablet").getValue(String.class);
                final String gettotal = Requests.child("total").getValue(String.class);


                // final String getproductName = Requests.child("productName").getValue(String.class);


                String getProductName = "";
                if (Requests.hasChild("foods")) {
                    for (DataSnapshot foodSnapshot : Requests.child("foods").getChildren()) {

if(foodSnapshot.hasChild("productName"){
  getProductName += foodSnapshot.child("productName").getValue(String.class); 
}                    
                    }
                }
                // creating user item with user details
                MyItems myItems = new MyItems(getaskfor, gettablet, gettotal, getproductName);

                // adding this user item to List
                myItemsList.add(myItems);
```

// add blank space if required: getProductName += getProductName + " ";

** You are also forgeting concatenate all the product names, so thats why you always get the last product name but not the others.